# Cannot change value of certain parts of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

Im trying to change the rows of an array with new values in a `for loop`, but cannot get it to work.

Problem is related to propagation of a wave packet in quantum physics.

Ive tried using the `numpy.dot()` function, but that doesnt work, and i tried making an easier `for loop`, that works.

```
import numpy as np

sig = 10**(-8)

x0 = 50*10**(-9)

L = 200*10**(-9)

N = 400

Nx = 1000

x = np.linspace(x0, L, N)

expsig = np.exp(-((1/2)*(x-x0)**2)/(sig**2))

expimg = np.exp(1j*(x-x0))

Phi = (1/(np.pi**(1/4)*np.sqrt(sig))*expsig*expimg)

Boxfunc = np.zeros(shape = (N, Nx))

for i in range(0, N):

    SINnpi = np.sin(((i*np.pi)/L)*x)
    Boxfunc[i,:] = np.sqrt(2/L)*SINnpi
    Y = Boxfunc[i,:]*Phi
```

I expect the output to be a 400x1000 array with new calculated values from the multiplication between Phi and Boxfunc.

I just get the error message "could not broadcast input array from shape (400) into shape (1000)" when i get to the Boxfunc in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with array `x`, it should be `x = np.linspace(x0, L, Nx)`, then your code works.
Or you can define `Boxfunc = np.zeros(shape = (Nx, N))`. The problem is from the shape between `x` and `Boxfunc`.